# How do I specify lifetimes such that a local referenced value is distinct from a passed in reference?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm creating a local struct (`second`) which contains a reference to a local variable (`wrapper`). This local variable, in turn, references a larger lifetime (`'a`). How do I show the compiler, that the lifetime of the local variable doesn't need to be as large as that larger lifetime?

This problem is reproduced by the following code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=82bb5009248dd39d52c2d61d4d088fa4)):

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Abc {}

struct ImplAbc;
impl Abc for ImplAbc {}

struct WrappingAbc<'a, A> {
    value: &'a A,
}
impl<'a, A: Abc> Abc for WrappingAbc<'a, A> {}
impl<'a, A: Abc> WrappingAbc<'a, A> {
    fn new(value: &'a A) -> Self {
        WrappingAbc { value }
    }
}

struct AnotherWrapper<'a, K, A, S> {
    value: &'a A,
    other: usize,
    phantom_data: PhantomData<(K, S)>,
}
impl<'a, A: Abc, S: Strategy<KindOne, A>> AnotherWrapper<'a, KindOne, A, S> {
    fn new(value: &'a A) -> Self {
        AnotherWrapper {
            value,
            other: 0,
            phantom_data: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
impl<'a, 'b, A: Abc, S: Strategy<KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'b, A>>>
    AnotherWrapper<'a, KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'b, A>, S>
{
    fn replace_value<SOther: Strategy<KindOne, A>>(
        old: AnotherWrapper<KindOne, A, SOther>,
        newvalue: &'a WrappingAbc<'b, A>,
    ) -> Self {
        AnotherWrapper {
            value: newvalue,
            other: old.other,
            phantom_data: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
trait Kind {}
struct KindOne;
impl Kind for KindOne {}
struct KindTwo;
impl Kind for KindTwo {}

trait Strategy<K: Kind, A: Abc>: Sized {}
struct StrategyImpl;
impl<K: Kind, A: Abc> Strategy<K, A> for StrategyImpl {}

fn f<'a, A: Abc, SOne: Strategy<KindOne, A>, STwo: Strategy<KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'a, A>>>(
    x: &'a A,
) {
    let first = AnotherWrapper::<KindOne, A, SOne>::new(x);
    let wrapper = WrappingAbc::new(x);
    let second = AnotherWrapper::<KindTwo, WrappingAbc<A>, STwo>::replace_value(first, &wrapper);
    move_away(second);
}

fn move_away<'a, A: Abc, S: Strategy<KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'a, A>>>(
    _argument: AnotherWrapper<'a, KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'a, A>, S>,
) {
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `wrapper` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:62:88
   |
57 | fn f<'a, A: Abc, SOne: Strategy<KindOne, A>, STwo: Strategy<KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'a, A>>>(
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
62 |     let second = AnotherWrapper::<KindTwo, WrappingAbc<A>, STwo>::replace_value(first, &wrapper);
   |                  ----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^-
   |                  |                                                                     |
   |                  |                                                                     borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                  argument requires that `wrapper` is borrowed for `'a`
63 |     move_away(second);
64 | }
   | - `wrapper` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How can I change the lifetime definitions such that `wrapper` is not required to live as long as `'a`, given that `second` is moved right after anyways? I suspect that this is related to the definition of `move_away`, because when I modify that line to this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5001efa11e9f30989d49e57cfb4a1755)):

```rust
fn move_away<'a, A: Abc, S: Strategy<KindTwo, A>>(_argument: AnotherWrapper<'a, KindTwo, A, S>) {}
```

the code compiles.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you better to identify and solve your problem :)

Comment: I fear that if I cut down more, I'll remove complexity that necessitates the solution direction I'm currently working towards. I don't think the problem will make sense with less information. I tried to simplify as much as possible already. Do you have any further reduction tips?

Comment: One should always seek to make an example so that other people can reproduce the problem themselves. The [Rust tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) contains a bit more guidance towards making an MCVE. You may also consider sharing a link to the [Playground](//play.rust-lang.org).

Comment: What is the definition of `ReturnType`? For this question we at least need to know whether it has a lifetime parameter. As stated by other commenters before, it would be best to provide a playground example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `ReturnType` doesn't have any type parameters, I added it to the list. I am trying to create an even more minimal problem in the Playground, but I'm having a hard time reproducing my problem.

Comment: @vandenheuvel Thanks for the info – in that case I don't know why you get this error, and I would need to see a full example reproducing the problem. You can start with your full code and remove bits that aren't relevant.

Comment: I tried to replicate the error by filling in the gaps with whatever seemed most appropriate, but [this compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2151db32ed80a70e12f957b13cc13cb6), which makes it almost certain that the actual error is somewhere in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I tried that, it made no difference. Here is a link to the playground, where I have a working version of what I'm trying to achieve in the real code base. I'm not successful in reproducing my issue there, it compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=722d5f244774213ad0fec4f41c51c943

Comment: @vandenheuvel OK, it was just a guess, since I can't see any problem with the code you showed. If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help fixing it. As I suggested before, you should start with a copy of your actual code and remove irrelevant bits, and verify that the error is still occurring after each step. This will help you to either understand the error yourself, or to create an example reproducing the problem that you can share.

Comment: @trentcl Thank you for the effort; I also made a compiling version (see two comments back). Could you explain why you decided to make `AdaptedMatrixProvider` a trait with a type argument, instead of a generic struct? In my specific case, I need only one version, but are there other benefits?

Comment: That was just a guess at your real code, based on the fact that `Tableau::from_artificial_with_provider` accepts an argument of type `&Wrapper`, but `new_simple` looks like it should be a constructor. You provided a definition of `Wrapper` but not `AdaptedMatrixProvider`, so I figured it could be a trait. There is no design principle or justification behind it; the example is too incomplete and abstract for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the definition of `move_away` to the following solves the compilation error:

```rust
fn move_away<'a, 'b, A: Abc, S: Strategy<KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'b, A>>>(
    _argument: AnotherWrapper<'a, KindTwo, WrappingAbc<'b, A>, S>
) {}
```

Introducing the lifetime `'b` removes the requirement that the lifetime of the inner `WrappingAbc` is just as long as `'a` as specified by the parent function.